# Zend Framework: translatable content inside a model

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, internationalization, model

I have a model in my app that takes care of creating the initial database structure (sort of an installer). I recently added translatable content (uses gettext). I would like to make the initial content language dependent.

What's the best way to use translatable content inside a model? Is there a way to use the `view->translate()` function inside the model or do I need to pass the already translated strings from the outside, e.g. as a parameter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you have bootsraped Zend_Locale and Zend_Translate, and they are saved in the Zend_Registry (by default they are in registry under keys 'Zend_Locale' and 'Zend_Translate' respectively)  you can access `translate()` method in your models  as follows:

```
    /*@var $translator Zend_Translate */
    $translator = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');

    /*@var $adapter Zend_Translate_Adapter */
    $adapter = $translator->getAdapter();

    var_dump($adapter->translate('Text to be translated'));
```

The translation in the above example will be performed according to your Zend_Locale.

And what would be the best way to translate data in your models? I'm not sure. If you want to make the translation 'invisible' or 'transparent' to your controllers or even models, you could maybe overload magical methods __get and __set of Zend_DB_Table_Row and embed translate() method there.

Comment: Wow, perfect answer, just what I was after. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: How to handle jquery validate messages? any Idea or suggestion.